# Filtering ifconfig output

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Im trying to select the First 3 octets of the IPv4 IP from ifconfig. How would i go about doing this. I just cant figure out how to select from this step

```
[root@hostname ~]# ifconfig | grep "inet addr:"  | grep -v "127.0.0.1" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
addr:10.20.1.3
```

what i ultimately want is `10.20.1` for final output

Comment: BTW, the output of the newer `ip addr` is easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Using only awk, for all interfaces:

```
ifconfig | awk '/Link encap/{eth=$1} ; /inet addr/{sub(/addr:/, "", $2) ; sub(/\.[0-9]*$/,"",$2) ; addr=$2 ; print eth, addr)'
```

Results:

```
eth0 192.168.0
lo 127.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the IP address of `eth0`, this should do it:

```
ifconfig | grep -A1 eth0 | grep "inet addr" | sed 's/inet addr://' | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even bother using `sed` for the actual address. It's more transparent (and easier to get right) to use `cut` for this!

Add `| sed -e 's/inet_addr://' | cut -d. -f 1-3` to the end of your original command:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr:"  | grep -v "127.0.0.1" | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/inet_addr://' | cut -d. -f 1-3
```

Or just use `cut` instead of `awk`:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr:"  | grep -v "127.0.0.1" | cut -w -f 2 | sed -e 's/inet_addr://' | cut -d. -f 1-3
```